# Methods called on jest mocked response fails with error

Tags: jestjs

I have the below line in my service.

```
  const timeline = await buildClient.getBuildTimeline(project.id, buildId);
```

The above code is successfully mocked by jest as below using the `__mocks__` approach.

```js
jest.mock('azure-devops-extension-api', () => {
  return { getClient: (client: any) => new GitRestClient() };
});

export const mockGetItems = jest
  .fn()
  .mockReturnValue({ records: [{ state: 2, type: 'TASK', task: { id: TASK_IDS[0] } }] });

class GitRestClient {
  public getBuildTimeline(projectId: string, buildId: string): Promise<Timeline[]> {
    return new Promise((resolve) => resolve(mockGetItems()));
  }
}
```

But when I get error during jest test in the below `find` method which acts upon the mocked response.

```
  const record = timeline.records.find((rec) => {
    return rec.type === 'Task';
  });
```

How should I update so that the above code snippet is mocked perfectly to return the record value using the `find` method.

Comment: You need to do override the `getBuildTimeLine` function with the mock. Like: `var x = new GitRestClient(); x. getBuildTimeline = mockGetItems;`. Something like that

Comment: GitRestClient is itelf a mocked class. updated the question to add details about it.